# generate IHS plugins to point to WAS cli

Tags: websphere, was, ibmhttpserver

I'm trying to generate a plugin-cfg.xml file for IBM HTTP Server (IHS) to point to a WebSphere Application Server (WAS) environment. I've tried using several commands and tools to generate the file, but they don't seem to be working for my specific environment. Can anyone recommend a reliable way to generate the plugin-cfg.xml file for IHS on my system? I'm running WAS version 9.5. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

We tried several commands and options to generate a plugin-cfg.xml file for IBM HTTP Server (IHS) to point to a WebSphere Application Server (WAS) environment from the command line. However, these commands did not work as expected or were not applicable for your specific environment.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt write what did you try and how it is not working.

Brief solutions are described here: [3 ways to generate the plugin-cfg.xml](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/3-ways-generate-plugin-cfgxml).

If you want to do it via cmd line this should work for you:

```
app_server_root/bin/GenPluginCfg.sh
```

You have detailed description here - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-zos/8.5.5?topic=SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_genplugincfg1.htm